# onActivityResult not called in fragment dialog via custom adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

Fairly new to Android. I've the following scenario:

1. App starts in Main Activity and here I add a fragment
2. In that fragment is a listview populated with a custom adapter, I am passing an instance of the `FragmentActivity` to the adapter.
   Call:

   ```
   ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter new ExpandableListAdapter(mContext, mActivity, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
   ```

Implementation:

```
 public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, FragmentActivity activity, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._activity = activity;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }
```

3. When you click an item in the list, it opens a dialog with edittext fields namely: Name, Surname, Cell. I am passing the FragmentActivity to the dialog as the context:

   ```
   txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   final Dialog dialog = new SelectContactDialog(_activity);
                   dialog.show();
               }
           });
   ```
4. Then when you focus any of the 3 fields a Select contact opens up, I am using the passed FragmentActivity to call startActivityForResult like so:

   ```
   private class ContactListener extends Activity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener
   {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if (hasFocus) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
               _activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACTS_RESULT);
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

           if (requestCode == CONTACTS_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               String cell = "?", firstName = "?", lastName = "?";

               uriContact = data.getData();

               Cursor cursor = null;

               mCell.setText(cell);
               mLastName.setText(lastName);
               mFirstName.setText(firstName);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Everything works fine up until this point. So my problem now is I would like to get the results when a user selects a contact. I tried below but the `onActivityResult` override method is never called. I've no idea what to do and seems that other people have had a different from mine and their solutions doesn't work for me.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: you can use interface for that

Comment: Would you please give me an example?

Comment: when a user selects a contact you can call a method in your Main Activity and pass selected contact info as an argument like this: ((Main Activity) context).onContactSelection(contact); and do whatever you want to do in it as you are doing in onActivityResult now

Comment: googling for that

Comment: @UsmanRana, where would I call that method from?

Comment: from your adapter, on click of any contact or view you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone you for your help. I changed the SelectContactDialog from dialog to activity and I've never been happier! I am new so I am learning the right way to go about things.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend to use an interface for this. For example create the interface `ContactCallback` which you have to implement in your activity. When you create your adapter, pass `this` (which means the interface). When you click on an item call inside your adapter the passed callback like `callback.onContactSelected()`. Inside `onContactSelected()` which is implemented in your activity you can open your dialog.

**Update:**

To your problem that your `onActivityResult()` is never called:

Is there a line in your manifest called `"android:launchMode="singleTask"`? Remove it and it should be called. Following cases can cause an issue with receiving the result:

- check you are using `startActivityForResult()` correctly, do not use `startActivity()`.
- if you do something in overriden `onBackPressed` method, `super.onBackPressed();` has to be positioned at the last of the method, not at the first line.
- remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in manifest or equivalent argument to create a intent.
- remove `noHistory="true"` in manifest of the called activity.
- check `setResult()` is missed.
- `finish()` is called to close the activity. use `finishActivity()` to close called activity.
- use requestCode more than zero. negative value does not work.

Comment: I managed to get the results by implementing the `onActivityResult` in the `MainActivity`. My only issue now is update the dialog fields (cell, display_name) with the contact details.

Comment: thank you for your help. I changed the SelectContactDialog from dialog to activity and I've never been happier! I am new so I am learning the right way to go about things.

Answer (score -2):

You need to call this to get your `onActivityResult` called. on your dialog while your are closing put this code

```
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    finish();
```

Comment: puting a result ok value inside intent is not a good idea for sorting onactivityresult.